# Select database from another app android when device rooted

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a rooted device. I have chmod 777 for folder and file in an app. I can open its database by code below.

```
private Context context;
private String path = "/data/data/.../databases/database_name";
private String table = "table_name";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public void openDatabase() throws Exception{
   db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
   Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

I can copy the database to another app (chmod 777). But I can't select from table_name.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 776): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM table_name

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: My device can't do this, but my friend 's device can do this after rooted. Two devices rooted same too.